# How do you keep highlighted text highlighted? Virtual list

Tags: javascript, react-virtualized

I need to be able to let users highlight many rows, but the issue is that the rows highlighted become unhighlighted if the user scrolls too far. Although increasing the buffer helps, it doesn't solve the problem.

An example of what I'm looking for is if you go to GitHub Actions and have an action that has had a lot of logs output. They're using a virtual list here but if you highlight text and scroll far away and then scroll back, the text remains highlighted.